# В webbrowser  включить возможность эмулировать нажатие клавиши enter.

Tags: delphi, iwebbrowser2

Вот у меня такая ситуация, я "листаю" ссылки в окне компонента имитируя нажатия клавиши `Tab`. Добравшись до нужной мне ссылки, по имитации нажатия клавиши `enter` должен осуществляться переход. Однако - нечего не происходит. А очень нужно заставить программу перейти по ссылке.

Также касательно прокрутки того же компонента. Его можно прокрутить программно? И как можно регулировать масштаб страницы в компоненте?

Comment: @Авада Кедавра, Уточните, какой язык. Также поясните условия, в которых должно работать приложение.

Comment: язык Делфи (паскаль).
Вот то что  я хочу:
заходим программно на сайт. Программа имитирует скажем 6-кратное нажатие таб. Попадаем на нужную ссылку. Задача - перейти по ней программно.
Варианты следующие:
или навести мышку на выделенную ссылку, затем программно её нажать, или нажать программно ЕНТЕР.
Но в компоненте последнее не проходит  в отличии от обычного броузера скажем мозилы. Вот такая вот проблема!

Comment: я так понял что для местных программеров оказалось невозможным решить подобную задачку...
Гы..слабовато.. сразу в закрыто перевели и забыли! Молодцы!
Предлагаю обозвать сайт - помощь новичкам от новичков!
Удачи!

Comment: @Авада Кедавра, и вам всего доброго.

Answer (score 1):

масштаб регулируется довольно просто

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Body.Style.Zoom:= число; //например, 0.75 - 75%, 3-300%, и т.д
```

прокрутка осуществляется следующим образом:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.ParentWindow.ScrollBy(x, y);//например, (0,100)-прокрутка вниз на 100 пикселей, (-10,0)-прокрутка влево на 10 пикселей
```

Нажать программно клавишу <kbd>ENTER</kbd> в компоненте WebBrowser можно так:

```
SendMessage(webbrowser1.handle, WM_KEYDOWN,VK_RETURN,0);
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!  Сильно помогли, а то я кучу времени потратил так и не нашёл нечего нужного мне.

Ещё раз спасибо!  Выручили!!!

Comment: Не забываем принять ответ :)